# Is there any way to pass a Flow into a Room DAO Query method?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, kotlin-coroutines

I'm working on implementing Room in an android app and I have a use case where I am receiving a Flow with the current user id for functionality similar to switching which logged in Google user to view a service as. I'd like to pass that flow into a @Query annotated method in my DAO to get user widgets so that if the currently selected user changes or the list of widgets stored changes, the output Flow<List> would change as well.

Something like

WidgetRepo.kt

```
val widgets: Flow<List<Widget>> = widgetDAO.getWidgetsByUser(currentUserID)
```

WidgetDao.kt

```
@Query("select * from widget where userID = :userID")
fun getWidgetsByUser(userID: Flow<Int>): Flow<List<Widget>>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that's a good practice. I would rather do the following logic in a specific use-case, for example:

```
class GetWidgetsByUserUseCase(
    private val userRepo: UserRepository,
    private val widgetLocalSource: WidgetRepository
){

    suspend operator fun invoke() = userRepo.flatMapLatest { user ->
            widgetLocalSource.getWidgetsByUser(user.id)
        }

}
```

With this implementation every time a new user is emitted, the `widgetLocalSource.getWidgetsByUser()` will be triggered and the previous flows will be canceled.

See [flatMapLatest](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/flat-map-latest.html) for more information on the operator.

Answer (score -2):

Room Database has supported Flow since before. Add this to gradle:

```
 // Kotlin Extensions and Coroutines support for Room - latest Room version 2.3.0
 implementation("androidx.room:room-ktx:$room_version")
```

See more [Write observable queries with Room](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/async-queries#observable) here.

Comment: The link is for getting a flow out of room, not for passing a flow in as a parameter.